# Vagrant ansible git clone permission error

Tags: git, ssh, vagrant, ansible, vagrantfile

I am using vagrant with ansible provision. When I am doing git clone with from ansible I am getting following error:

```
failed: [default] => {"cmd": "/usr/bin/git ls-remote '' -h refs/heads/HEAD", "failed": true, "rc": 128}
stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

msg: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

But when ever I am trying to clone from vagrant box manually it works fine. I have searched net and I have got ssh forwarding set to true in vagrant and my ~/.ssh/config looks like following which allows forwarding from host machine.

```
Host            *
  ForwardAgent  yes
```

My ansible yml file is as follows:

```
---
- hosts: all
  sudo: true
  tasks:
    - name: Clone project
      git: repo=<git ssh link>
           accept_hostkey=yes
           clone=yes
           dest=/home/vagrant
```

My Vagrant file is as follows:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 9000
  config.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
  end
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
end
```

One more question whenever I am doing git clone from ansible why it runs following command instead of git clone:

```
/usr/bin/git ls-remote '' -h refs/heads/HEAD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet is on that Ansible doesn't do SSH key forwarding (ForwardAgent yes) with your config.

Possible suggested workaround is to create a deployment specific keys, use Ansible to set them up in the deployment target and then use these keys to do the clone.

E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29727859/315168